# Win32 How to bring a modeless dialog box to the top

Tags: winapi, dialog, win32gui

I have a set of modeless dialog boxes open, but I can't for the life of me click on one of them get it to appear in the foreground. It gets focus, but the dialog boxes forever remain in the order on the screen that they were created. The last one created is always in the foreground, obscuring (or partially obscuring) the others.

I have tried:

- SetActiveWindow(hDlg);
- SetForegroundWindow(hDlg);
- SwitchToThisWindow(hDlg, FALSE);

in response to a WM_LBUTTONUP message, but though they get called they do nothing. I have tried different configurations in the dialog box properties like playing with the 'SetForground' or 'Topmost' parameters and they do nothing.

Am I trying to do an impossible task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing this is window ownership. An owned window is always shown above its owner. This is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Clearly you have ownership relationships between your modeless dialogs. You can resolve this by making each of the modeless dialogs be owned by the same window.

Exactly how you do about controlling ownership depends on how you are creating these dialogs. If you are using `CreateDialog` then the third parameter is used to specify the dialog's owner.

Comment: Bless you! I have been pulling hairs all day to try and solve that. Set that parent parameter to NULL and that does it; the exe is the parent. I guess I knew that at one time because a massive Win32 program I wrote 9 years ago worked. 9 years and one remembers SOME things ... but not all.

Comment: Do you have a main window? Normally you'd expect that to be the owner of your modeless dialogs.

Comment: Actually I do not. My main window IS a modeless dialog

Comment: If you set the owner to be NULL that would be fine. But all your dialogs will have taskbar buttons

Comment: Why don't you set the modeless dialog that is your main window as the owner of the others.